# How to add a launcher to a program/script inside my home dir?

Tags: gnome-panel, gnome2

I'm still using Gnome 2, and I want to add a launcher to gnome-panel that will run: `~/bin/foobar.sh`.

However, when I tried that, it gives me: *Failed to execute child process "~/bin/foobar.sh" (No such file or directory)*

I also tried `$HOME/bin/foobar.sh`, same issue.

I don't want to add the absolute path to the script, I want to add a path relative to my home dir.

(also, `~/bin` is added to `PATH` at `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile`, so it isn't added while gnome starts up)

---

Extra information:

```
$ ls -l ~/bin/foobar.sh 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 username group 25 2012-01-17 18:26 /full/path/to/home/username/bin/foobar.sh -> ../other_scripts/foobar.sh*
```

In other words, `~/bin/foobar.sh` is a symlink to a script in another directory, and that script has the +x bit set. I can run `~/bin/foobar.sh` without problems inside a terminal, so the issue is not in the script.

What I'm trying to do is to right-click on the gnome-panel and add a custom launcher. Then I write `~/bin/foobar.sh` as the command, but when I try to click on the launcher, it gives me the errors I mentioned above.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the problem, but is the script set as executable?

Comment: You have a 'bin' directory in every user's home directory? Could you provide the output of `ls -l ~/bin/foobar.sh`?

Comment: IMO, in scripts it is best to use the full path to your script.

Comment: Updated the question with requested information.

Comment: Also, I don't want to use the full path because this home is shared with another computer, and in that other computer the home directory is in another path.

Answer (score 0):

The panel launchers don't do the same expansion of special characters as bash does, so `~` and `$HOME` don't do what you think...

The easiest solution is probably to use `bash -c "~/bin/foobar.sh"` as the command.